# What is the equivalent to UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged when using x:Bind?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyTitle, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Is there an equivalent to this when using `x:Bind`?

If I use it like this, it only updates when focus is changed.

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Is your property using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?  This interface should get the ui to update when the value changes

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` sends a notification to the view model whenever the text changes. That means, every key-stroke is sent to the view model. If you use the default, it will update the view model when the user navigates away from `TextBox`. `x:Bind` on its own behaves like the default, not like PropertyChanged.

Comment: I do not see UpdateSourceTrigger as supported by x:Bind https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204783.aspx

Comment: Have you ever managed to find a workaround for this? I have a similar issue and it's driving me crazy

Comment: @NickGoloborodko sorry no solution yet. You can create a behavior that `x:Binds` the text with `PropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone reading this after 2017, `UpdateSourceTrigger` has now been added and is described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#properties-that-you-can-set-with-xbind). I believe it was added in Fall Creators Update (build 16299), so if your min version is 16299 or higher you will be able to use `UpdateSourceTrigger`.

If you're targeting an older version of Windows you will have to keep using `Binding`.

Answer (score 9):

Ken Tucker is right, there is no UpdateSourceTrigger property for x:Bind and it behaves as it was set to PropertyChanged, except in case of TextBox when it triggers on lost focus. Check the bottom of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210946.aspx) page.
So you have to keep using Binding in this case.